# ons.notification.alert表示中にAndroid端末のbackボタン

Tags: onsen-ui

よろしくお願い致します。

onsen-ui、AnglarJS、cordovaを利用してAndroidアプリを開発しています。
Android端末の backボタンの取扱いについて苦慮しています。

メインとなるページ(ons-pageで定義)に関しては、ng-device-backbutton属性を
指定することで、アプリ終了の確認メッセージを表示できているのですが、
ons.notification.alertでダイアログを表示中にbackボタンを押すと
何も表示されずにアプリが終了してしまいます。
これを回避する方法はありますでしょうか？